# Angular modal-window close confirmation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an angular-ui modal window, and, obviously, when I click outside the modal(backdrop) the modal closes.

However, I would like to change this behavior, for example, when I click on the backdrop, the popup window shows up with 2 buttons (OK and Cancel) and the modal will NOT close on Cancel.

The popup phase is easy, but I am not sure how to stop the modal from closing.

Could anybody help me with this, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Give `backdrop : 'static'` so that It won't close when you click outside the modal. http://plnkr.co/edit/T1FjpoNBItvh3Vj8bHdI?p=preview

Comment: Yes that is my temporal solution, but I would like to make it work as mentioned. Thanks anyway for answering!

Answer (score 2):

As Hurix mentioned, Give

```
backdrop : 'static'
```

in your modal options which will not close the modal window when backdrop is closed.
Then apply a click event on backdrop:

```
$('.modal-backdrop').on('click', function(){
    if (confirm('close modal') == true){
    //dismiss your modal instance
    } else {
        //return
    }
});
```

This click function will give a confirmation popup with `ok` and `cancel` button and you can handle whatever you want to do when they are clicked.

Comment: This is exactly what am I looking for, but I am afraid that it does not work for me. The method is not even fired. Could You provide additional info, please?

Comment: events are working with this function header, however, if I replace header with backdrop, event does not work..
    $(document).on("click", ".modal-header", function() {}